# Sort array of HTML based on output

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So I have an array of HTML links;

```
[
    "<a href=\"...\" target=\"_blank\">foo</a>",
    "<a href=\"...\" target=\"_blank\">apple</a>",
    "<a href=\"...\" target=\"_blank\">cucumber</a>"
]
```

And I want to sort it based on the user-facing output of it (i.e. the `a` tag's content);

```
[
    "<a href=\"...\" target=\"_blank\">apple</a>",
    "<a href=\"...\" target=\"_blank\">cucumber</a>",
    "<a href=\"...\" target=\"_blank\">foo</a>"
]
```

I imagine I'd have to strip the HTML tags and then `.sort()` that, but I have no idea how to then reconcile that with the original array. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery or looking for vanilla Javascript solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the HTML and get the content of the tags.

By not using a regex, the markup can be anything as long as the selectors match, which is usually what you want as regex [isn't really capable of parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Then use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to compare the strings, this avoids issues with case sensitivity and special characters that you would have with `<` or `>`

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    var docA = new DOMParser().parseFromString(a, "text/html");
    var docB = new DOMParser().parseFromString(b, "text/html");
    var txtA = docA.querySelector('a').innerHTML;
    var txtB = docB.querySelector('a').innerHTML;

    return txtA.localeCompare(txtB);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/A875E/2/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex and a comparison function to easily do this.

```
var arr = [
    "<a href=\"...\" target=\"_blank\">foo</a>",
    "<a href=\"...\" target=\"_blank\">apple</a>",
    "<a href=\"...\" target=\"_blank\">cucumber</a>"
]

function compFunc(a,b){
   return a.match(/>(.*)</)[1] > b.match(/>(.*)</)[1];
}

console.log(arr.sort(compFunc))
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Htw4F/1/)

The regex will match anything between the closing `>` and the following opening `<` (need to ensure what's between them doesn't contain those chars), and the parentheses around `(.*)` mean it's a capture group and in the array returned from `.match()` will have the contents of that capture group (the string we want) as the second element.

Comment: +1 - Didn't see your answer when posting mine! Wouldn't have posted the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You pass `sortfunction` parameter to `sort method`:

```
var arr = [
    "<a href=\"...\" target=\"_blank\">foo</a>",
    "<a href=\"...\" target=\"_blank\">apple</a>",
    "<a href=\"...\" target=\"_blank\">cucumber</a>"
];

var sorted = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = strip(a);
    b = strip(b)
    return a.localCompare(b);
}
```

Here's how you do the strip: [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)